# Can I compare regression coefficients from different models with the same predictors and outcome?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

**My question**: *Can I compare regression coefficients from different models with the same predictors and outcome?*

**Sample context**: let's say I have individual-level survey data from 12 different months and I want to run the same regression (i.e., exact same predictors/outcome) separately for each time period. So 1 regression for January, using the data collected in January, and so on...

Would I then be able to compare the regression coefficients (e.g., for the 1st predictor: X1) across the 12 models? That is, can I compare the confidence intervals for the same predictor (e.g., X1) across models to see if there are significant changes in the predictive power of X1 over time?

- I know I could formally test whether the predictive effect of X1 changes over time, by aggregating the data and running a single model with an interaction term between month and X1. However, doesn't this unnecessarily complicate the interpretation? (especially if month is entered as an unordered categorical variable?)
- To clarify, I'm **not** talking about panel data: i.e., if the total sample is N = 12,000 (with N = 1,000 per month), we'll assume here that all 12,000 people are different.

If this question has already been answered, my apologies -- I did look around before posting here.

Comment: Is your final goal to test whether the twelve datasets differ significantly?

Comment: sure, why not? Although having one model might be a better option anyway

Comment: Think harder about model specification.  This is not a place for separate models but instead a place for modeling calendar time (smoothly and cyclically) interacting with variables whose importance you suspect changes over time.